# FFMPEG - Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-encoding

I want to play an RTSP live stream that I get internally. I'm using ffplay to play this. And this is the command that I use :
`ffplay -i "rtsp://test.vibrtech.com/mov/video.sav?MAC=00C2100F124&channel=2&GUID=betauser"`, but when I execute, I get Invalid data found when processing input error. The complete error output is given below:

```
D:\..>ffplay -i "rtsp://test.vibrtech.com/mov/video.sav?MAC=00C2100F124&channel=2&GUID=betauser"
ffplay version N-77816-g9ca64c3 Copyright (c) 2003-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads 
--enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls 
--enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca 
--enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm
--enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb 
--enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp 
--enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora
--enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp
 --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
--enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
libavutil      55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
libavcodec     57. 22.100 / 57. 22.100
libavformat    57. 21.101 / 57. 21.101
libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
libavfilter     6. 23.100 /  6. 23.100
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
rtsp://test.vibrtech.com/mov/video.sav?MAC=00C2100F124&channel=2&GUID=betauser: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: I get the same error when trying to create and RSTP stream from an h.264. Did you ever find a solution to your problem?